# MessageSource bean injected null in custom exception mapper class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand why the messageSource bean is injected null in the below code :

```
@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>{
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;


@Override
public Response toResponse(BadRequestException ex) {
    String message = null;
    try{
    message = messageSource.getMessage(ex.getErrorCode().getErrorKey(),null,null);

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.status(400).entity(message).type("text/plain")
            .build();
   }

}
```

Below is my applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.infonexis" />
<context:annotation-config />

<import resource="applicationPersistence.xml" />
<import resource="applicationService.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-datasource.xml" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename">
<value>MessageResources_en_US</value>
</property>
<property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I am trying to autowire the MessageSource bean in the custom exception mapper classes but it is injected null, Previously it was working when I loaded the context from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as shown below :

```
@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>{

@Override
public Response toResponse(BadRequestException ex) {
    String message = null;
    try{
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    MessageSource messageSource = 
     (MessageSource)context.getBean("messageSource");

    message = messageSource.getMessage(ex.getErrorCode().getErrorKey(),null,null);

    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.status(400).entity(message).type("text/plain")
            .build();
  }

}
```

I have tried to the following

1. Implement the org.springframework.context.MessageSourceAware interface
2. add the @Component annotation to the BadRequestExceptionMapper class
3. Tried to inject a ReloadableresourceBundleMessageSource instead of using interface MessageSource

But everything has failed.

The context component scan is set correctly.
How can I get the MessageSource injected properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your @Provider has some context listener defined in your web.xml which is may be started before the spring application context listener.

*Try to put Spring listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener before the Web Services listener like com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener (or) your any JAX-RS servlet listener like jersey.*

Comment: Yes I have added a spring listener `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` already.
I somehow managed to fix this problem.
I injected AppicationContext and autowired it using its setter method.
This got the messageSource bean injected properly from the context but the messages were not picked up from the properties file
I got error saying __"message not found for code **** and locale ** "__
So I changed the message source from "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" to "ResourceBundleMessageSource" and its working now.

I am not sure if this is an ideal solution to the problem.